# How to disable some items in listview which is in the Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to disable some items in `ListView` which is in the `AlertDialog`.

How may I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supply your own custom `ListAdapter` to the `AlertDialog.Builder` via `setAdapter()`. You can then override `areAllItemsEnabled()` and `isEnabled()` to enable/disable whatever you want.

Comment: I want to dynamically disable some items, so I have to put some code in the onPrepareDialog method, how to change the item status at that moment?

Comment: @Chris: in `onPrepareDialog()`, call `makeTheseGoAwayPlease()` on your custom `Adapter`, which stores that information and uses it in its implementation of `isEnabled()`.

Comment: Beside that, I want inital some selected items, so can I do this in the     onPrepareDialog() ? How ?

Comment: @Chris: With Java code. You put the checkbox there -- you check it when it needs to be checked. If you were not using `setAdapter()`, you could use `setMultiChoiceItems()` and simplify this, but then you cannot have disabled entries. In all likelihood, this should not be an `AlertDialog` -- please consider using a dialog-themed activity instead.